# How do I inject assertion/assumptions in code under test?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, pex, intellitest

For my research I am using Intellitest on Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise. I read that it is possible to add assumptions and assertions to the parametrized unit test that Intellitest generates. Unfortunately I also need to add assumptions and assertions in the code under test. Is it possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

In the parameterized unit tests, you can use the PexAssume and PexAssert static classes (see the [MSDN sites](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.pex.framework.pexassume.aspx) for details).

In the code under test, you shall use Code Contracts. However, as far as I know, IntelliTest does not recognize them *currently* to generate test cases ([source](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/8759458-enable-intellitest-leverage-code-contracts)).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What if I put in the code under test a statement if (assumption_violated) throw new AssumptionViolatedException() and I catch it in the PUT, say: try { codeUnderTest(); } catch (AssumptionViolatedException e) { PexAssume.Fail(); } ?